# Why is the average of the scores I imput not showing?

Tags: java

I'm very new at Java, and somehow my code is not giving me the average, but it doesnt throw me errors, so I dont know where it's wrong.

```
 System.out.println("Please enter the amount of students: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int len = sc.nextInt();
    int students[] = new int[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the scores from the first examen of the student " + (i + 1) + " ");
        students[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The scores of the students are:" + Arrays.toString(students));
        float scores[] = new float[len];
        int sumScores = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            scores[i] = sc.nextInt();
            sumScores += scores[count];
            int average = sumScores / len;
            System.out.println("The average of all the scores are: " + average);
```

Comment: Stop and think about the logic of your code for a second.  If you were doing this on paper, would you calculate the average every time you added a new number to sum?  You would not, you would calculate at the end, AKA after the loop.  You are currently calculating the average every loop iteration.  Additionally, I don't see why you would use two separate arrays and loops to take the scores twice here, it can be done with just a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couples things that don't make sense here. I think we can agree the average is equal to the sum of all elements divided by the number of elements.

In your for loop, you are iterating through the loop and using count as the index, instead of `i`, which is redundant already, but you also *never increment count*. So it's also incorrect. So, just use i - that's part of the reason we do a for loop this way instead of `for element : list`.

```
// this
sumScores += scores[count]; // this is essentially scores[0] over and over

// should become this
sumScores += scores[i];
```

Next, move your "summarizing" prints outside of the loops. You don't want to print this every time.

Next tip: call `sc.nextLine()` after every call to `sc.nextInt()`, because `nextInt()` does not consume the newline character.

I was going to give you a working block of code - however it's not clear to me if you want to have one exam per student, or multiple exams, and an average of averages or something. If you're casting to a float I assume you want decimal places - so maybe look up how to do that type conversion without losing precision and decide where the best place to make that cast is. Cheers.

Comment: I corrected the part of i, but everytime I replace sc.nextInt() for sc.nextLine() throws me an error in the code and it also dont print my average

Comment: Note that I said to put `sc.nextLine()` **after** `sc.nextInt()`. Replacing it would naturally require you to `parseInt()` from your String that `nextLine()` returns

Answer (score 0):

If arrays and loops confuse you, you could also give functional programming a try.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of students: ");
        int len = sc.nextInt();

        double average = IntStream.generate(() -> {
            System.out.println("Enter the scores from the first examen of the student");
            return sc.nextInt();
        }).limit(len).average().orElse(0.0);

        System.out.println("The average of all the scores are: " + average);
```

Comment: That's amazing! I just used that and it worked, but its more advance that what I need, so I should learn how to use the arrays and loops first. Thanks again for your help